# Visual Studio 2017 Web App with SQL Authentication Error 52

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to publish a VS2017 web app to a godaddy domain with authentication on a remote SQL server. The app works fine when run from the Visual Studio environment.  I can log in, register, etc and see the data on my SQL Server. When deployed I get ::

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)]

Comment: Can you verify that the server you are deploying to can access the remote SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - I discovered that the web.config file on the domain server did not get updated with the proper connection string.